# cannot send signal to VGA using VGA-to-HDMI adapter

Tags: linux-mint, multi-monitor, hdmi

This is the output of `lspci -v`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c05d
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
        I/O ports at 1800 [size=8]
        Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at f0200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915
```

This is the output of `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 600, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1024x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 223mm x 125mm
   1024x600       60.0*+
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The problem is that I'm using an HDMI input via VGA adapter because my netbook only has a VGA output. As you can see, it seems the monitor is not connected but it is.

I already tried using `xrandr` with `--auto` and `--addmode` with no positive outcome on both VGA1 and VIRTUAL1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware question, this is a unix forum

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that your vga-to-hdmi adapter is working properly? maybe it needs to be powered (check USB-ports).
try to use it with other PCs, laptops,...

if the device is indeed working properly and it still cannot be detected with `xrandr`, you might try to *force* it. from `man xrandr`:

```
   Forces to use a 1024x768 mode on an output called VGA:
          xrandr --newmode "1024x768" 63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
          xrandr --addmode VGA 1024x768
          xrandr --output VGA --mode 1024x768
```

Comment: it's working in the sense that I don't get a "verify signal" when plugged in, it's just a black screen in standby. It has no power, it's just an extension of the vga port. I also have the same problem with my notebook job but they both have linux mint so I don't know if it's that the problem.

Comment: not sure, whether this qualifies as "working". anyhow, my question of "working" was more directed at the input side of the device: if the adapter recognized by other output-systems (try another laptop). can you somehow verify that it is not broken?

Comment: I tried a live Ubuntu and having the same problem. I should probably try to reinstall windows to see what happens.

Comment: or just visit a friend and try it on their laptop.

Comment: Of course I also used a different laptop :)

Comment: Is this just a passive plug adapter or is it a power device that does video conversion?  Because normally HDMI cables don't carry a VGA-compatible signal, so an ordinary adapter cable won't work.

Comment: That's true. Using standard passive cable you can only send VGA to HDMI, not other way round. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/222/can-a-simple-cable-convert-hdmi-output-to-vga