# Cannot get back signal after reboot using VGA-to-HDMI adapter

Tags: debian, xorg, debian-installer, hdmi, intel-graphics

I recently bought an [VGA to HDMI](http://www.amazon.ca/dp/B00K76K37M/) adapter for a HTPC (has a DisplayPort jack instead of HDMI, which got disabled when I put the TV Tuner in - long story - but VGA jack is still functional).  I got it today, and hooked it up.

I am a Debian user, so before really setting it up, I tested it on my netbook running Debian Wheezy (7.x).  Console didn't show, but that was no real surprise since the BIOS didn't display on the TV either.  The GUI, however, displayed in all it's glory.

I then proceeded to connect the HTPC and pop in a Debian Beta CD (Jessie v8) - with no other displays connected.  Surprisingly enough, the installer displayed on the TV. I then let the installer do it's thing, rebooted, and then, black screen, and never got it back.

I am able to ssh in, and run these commands:

```
root@slave:/home/media# xrandr -q
Can't open display 
root@slave:/home/media# lshw -c video
  *-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:fc000000-fc3fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:1c70(size=8)
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fc600000-fc6fffff
root@slave:/home/media# lspci -v

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkCentre M6258
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at fc000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 1c70 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3048
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at fc600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2

root@slave:/home/media#
```

The adapter is a powered device, and I doubt it spontaneously stopped working (though I can check that).  My last reboot I made sure the TV was on and set to the right input before restarting.  I am using the Intel Xorg driver, if that makes a difference, and the PC is a Lenovo M58 7360.

My problem is similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117885/cannot-send-signal-to-vga-using-vga-to-hdmi-adapter) but the situation is different in the end (they were using a passive device on a laptop with a functional screen to clone, and mine was found to work under certain situations, I just need to find out what those situations are).

UPDATE:

I blind-logged-in and ran (from ssh):

```
media@slave:~$ xrandr -display :0.0 -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    60.00  
media@slave:~$
```

I may have to define a lower resolution to continue.  So I am setting modes with xrandr, but none respond thus far (and no errors - including 640x480).

Comment: BTW, it's a Philips 32PFL733 TV - http://www.engadget.com/products/philips/32pfl733/specs/

Comment: I've had some similar issues in the past, and found that turning the TV/monitor off and then on again forced the TV to sync to the incoming signal and fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately, power cycling the TV didn't help.  As for whether the adapter is still working, I popped the install CD in a second time, and the install screen appeared.  So it seems the TV will only display in setup mode ... or when the laptop is used at 1024x768.